# Manipulating excel "autoshapes" with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro in VBA (Excel) that is assigned to a Checkbox. Whenever the checkbox is clicked, an "autoshape" will change its "order" from "Send to Back" to "Send to Front".

Basically, I am trying to create a dashboard with multiple panels, so that users can access information without moving between sheets. Each panel will have a rectangular autoshape as its background and the components of the panel will be "grouped" within the autoshape.

Can this be done? I would greatly appreciate any ideas into writing the code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite following your larger goal, but in order to bring a shape to the front use this:

```
If MyCheckBox.Value = True Then
    MySheetName.Shapes("MyShapeName").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If
```

You should select your desired ZOrder movement from the MsoZOrderCmd enumeration and your code should be in the Change event routine for your checkbox control.

---

EDIT:

You could also refer to the shape by its index number. For example:

```
MySheetName.Shapes(0).ZOrder msoBringToFront
```

Also, to get the name of a shape, either click it and look in the Name Box in the upper left corner of Excel (below the toolbars), or iterate through all the shapes like so:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim MyShape As Shape

For Each MyShape In Sheet1.Shapes

    Debug.Print MyShape.Name

Next MyShape

End Sub
```

Comment: Sub CheckBox3_Click()
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
    Sheet1.Shapes("blueoval").ZOrder msoBringToFront
End If
End Sub


This is the code that I entered.. Why do I get a Run Time Error 424?

Comment: Assuming that you get that error when setting the zorder, it means VBA can't find a shape by the name of "blueoval". You sure that's the name of the shape? You sure it's on Sheet1?